# how to map question options in my program

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i need to show my question options as a radio buttons in my popup module i have tried but i cant find one solutions
its my question module:

```
import questions from "./Data";
const QuestionModel = () => {
  return (
    <div className="modal-body">
      <div className="app">
        {questions.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <h3>{item.questionText}</h3>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and this is my sample data file:

```
const questions = [
    {
        questionText: 'What is the capital of France?',
        answerOptions: [
            { answerText: 'New York', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'London', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'Paris', isCorrect: true },
            { answerText: 'Dublin', isCorrect: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        questionText: 'Who is CEO of Tesla?',
        answerOptions: [
            { answerText: 'Jeff Bezos', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'Elon Musk', isCorrect: true },
            { answerText: 'Bill Gates', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'Tony Stark', isCorrect: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        questionText: 'The iPhone was created by which company?',
        answerOptions: [
            { answerText: 'Apple', isCorrect: true },
            { answerText: 'Intel', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'Amazon', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'Microsoft', isCorrect: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        questionText: 'How many Harry Potter books are there?',
        answerOptions: [
            { answerText: '1', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: '4', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: '6', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: '7', isCorrect: true },
        ],
    },
];
export default questions;
```

i need to show answer text as my options in my module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `answersOptions` is an array with **objects** inside, so you need to map through this array and display the *`object.answerText`*.

**Code:**

```
{questions.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <h3>{item.questionText}</h3>
              <div>
                {item.answerOptions.map((ans) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name={item.questionText}
                        id={item.questionText}
                      />
                      <label htmlFor={item.questionText}>
                        {ans.answerText}
                      </label>
                    </>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
```